# Highlighting Menu Bar Waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-waypoints

im in the process of making a site and would like to incorporate some of the things from this site into my menu.
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-tutorials/create-a-sticky-navigation-header-using-jquery-waypoints/
I'd really like my menu bar to change based on the section but am completely new to javascript and am having some trouble.  Right now, it doesn't appear to be working.  any suggestions?  thanks!  heres a bit of the code

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
        // Do our DOM lookups beforehand
        var nav_container = $(".nav-container");
        var nav = $("nav");
        nav_container.waypoint({
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        var sections = $('section');
        var navigation_links = $('nav a');
        sections.waypoint({
        handler: function(event, direction) {
        // handler code
        },
        offset: '35%'
        });
        var active_section;
        active_section = $(this);
        if (direction === "up") active_section = active_section.prev();
        var active_link = $('nav a[href="#' + active_section.attr("id") + '"]');
        navigation_links.removeClass("selected");
        active_link.addClass("selected");
        });

        $("li.nav-item").click(function() {
        $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $($(this).children().attr("href")).offset().top + "px"}, {duration: 500, easing: "swing"
        });
        return false;
        });
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').click(function(){
        // get the url of the picture we clicked
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        // get the url of the large image
        var bigUrl = $('.large-picture > img').attr('src');
        // change the url of the big picture
        $('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $(this).attr('src', bigUrl);
        });
        });

        });

    </script>
```

the menu bar
here is the menu bar as you can see below, it corresponds to marks throughout the html to which the nav causes a jump to

```
<div class = 'nav-container'>
    <nav>
        <div id = 'nav-items-container'>
            <ul class='nav-items'>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item'><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

a mark looks like this

```
<div class = 'mark' id = 'what'></div>
```

tags are used right before and right after each mark to set up the desired sections in which the nav will change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was working fine for me. I wrote a bunch of comments, so hopefully it's clear.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Smashing HTML5!</title>


    <style type="text/css">
    li { display:inline; background-color: #004900; padding: 4px; font-weight: bold;}
    li a { color:#fff; text-decoration: none;}

    .mark { position: absolute;  color: #fff; height: 500px; width: 100%; 
            font-size: 24px;  padding: 10px; padding-top: 50px;}

    #who{ top: 500px; background-color: #005600;}
    #what{ top: 1000px; background-color: #000078;}
    #how{ top: 1500px; background-color: #f30000;}
    #why{ top: 2000px; background-color: #00ff00;}
    #where{ top: 2500px; background-color: #000022;}

   .nav-container { z-index: 100;}

    </style> 


    <!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>  

    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <script src="js/IE8.js" type="text/javascript"></script><![endif]-->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ie6.css"/><![endif]-->

   <!-- DON'T FORGET TO CHANGE THESE PATHS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/jquery.1.10.2.min"></script>

    <script src="/waypoints/waypoints.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>



   <script>

        $(document).ready( function(){

       var wid;


      /*the shortcut below is all you need to make the menu
         stick to the top. --- make sure to load 
       waypoints-sticky.min.js as I have in the 
       <head> section*/
       $('.nav-container').waypoint('sticky');

        //helper function that does the high-lighting --- I've written it out 
        //step by step 
        function highlight(hl_id){
          $("li > a").css({ "background-color" : "#004900", "color": "#fff"});
          $("li").css({"background-color" : "#004900", "color": "#fff"});
          $("#" + hl_id + "-nav").css({"background-color" : "#f0f0f0", "color": "#000"});
          $("#" + hl_id + "-nav > a").css({ 
            "background-color" : "#f0f0f0", "color": "#000"});  
       }


      /* now we turn the marks into waypoints*/
      $('.mark').waypoint(function(direction) {

         /* now we get the id of the waypoint we're jumping to*/
           wid = $(this).attr("id");

     //if we're scrolling up we get "previous" waypoint
     if ( direction == 'up' ){

      var highlight_p = $('#' + wid).waypoint('prev');
      wid_p = highlight_p.attr("id");

        highlight(wid_p);

     }

    //if we're scrolling up we get last waypoint
    else if ( direction == 'down' ) {

      highlight(wid);  
    }





    });



   });//end doc ready




    </script>



    </head>

   <body id="index" class="home">

   <div class='nav-container' style="position:fixed;">
    <nav>
        <div id='nav-items-container'>
            <ul class='nav-items'>

                <li class='nav-item' id="who-nav"><a href='#who'>who</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item' id="what-nav"><a href='#what'>what</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item' id="how-nav"><a href='#how'>how</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item' id="why-nav"><a href='#why'>why</a></li>
                <li class='nav-item' id="where-nav"><a href='#where'>where</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    </div>



    <div class='mark' id='who'>who</div>
    <div class='mark' id='what'>what</div>
    <div class='mark' id='how'>how</div>
    <div class='mark' id='why'>why</div>
    <div class='mark' id='where'>where</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling waypoint inside another call to waypoint. Is this what you wanted to do?

```
 nav_container.waypoint({
    //first call to waypoint
        handler: function(direction) {
        nav_container.toggleClass('sticky', direction=='down');

        }
        //close handler
        var sections = $('section');
        var navigation_links = $('nav a');

        //second waypoint call
        sections.waypoint({
        handler: function(event, direction) {
        // handler code
        },
        offset: '35%'
        });
```

Can you describe how you want your menu to change and at what waypoint ( which element) ?
Also, it would be helpful if you could post some html.

Comment: the entire page is split up into different sections, all of which are represented in the menu bar.  Id like the nav on the menu bar to change blue when the view is on the section it corresponds to.  ill add some html now so you can get an idea of what im thinking.